# HTML5 Web Application

Tags: html, .htaccess, web-applications

Im in the process of building a HTML5 based web application which ideally would be made downloadable from a web based url via a link.

Should this link be clicked on a desktop machine, it would bring up some sort of overlay informing the user that they need to be on a mobile device to be allowed the download.

Basically Im looking for a way to enable the download only via a mobile device.

If anyone has a solution or can reference another page that does ( Ive looked but not been able to find anything ) it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a very broad question -- you won't get a ton of specific answers (you should try rephrasing your question to something more specific that we can answer); there are lots of solutions -- can you provide some foundation research other than "Ive looked but not been able to find anything)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two standard ways to do it:

- Check on client (parse UA or detect device features).
- Check on server (parse UA).

To parse UA use [ua-parser-js](https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js) on client and you will able to get device type `desktop`, `tablet` or `mobile`. Or with nodejs on server side (it allows you to hide algorithm). But UA parsing is not a assured method (because UA could easily be overwritten).

Device features detection depends on target device. You can check browser plugins, protocol support or something special. This is [an example of how does Apple checks iTunes support](http://ax.itunes.apple.com/detection/itmsCheck.js).